# Which socket descriptor receives the data if multiple connections set on same socket?

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, udp

I have a server program. The code snippet is given below;

```
int sd = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0);
....
//socket is set a a non blocking socket
....
bind(sd, (struct sockaddr *)&address, sizeof(address));
...
listen(sd, 3);
..
int i = 0;
while(TRUE) {
int new_sd[i] = accept(sd,sockadd,sockadd_len);
i++;
}
```

The scenario is that 3 clients are connected to this server/socket. When those clients start sending data to this server, which socket descriptor is going to have that (new_sd[0],new_sd[1],new_sd[2]) in the server? How the data will be distributed among different socket descriptors?

Comment: Based on client address that connected

Comment: Each descriptor returned by `accept()` is a distinct socket connection.  When a client sends data to your server, the corresponding socket will be in a readable state. Use `recv()` or `read()` to read that client's data from the appropriate socket descriptor.  Use `select()` or `(e)poll()` to know which socket descriptor(s) are in a readable state.

Answer (score 0):

The socket descriptor returned by `accept()` will contain the value that will communicate with the client that initiated the connection accepted by `accept()`.

You have the code:

```
int i = 0;
while(TRUE) {
    int new_sd[i] = accept(sd, sockadd, sockadd_len);
    i++;
}
```

This is a disaster.  You create a zero-length array (which is not valid standard C, despite anything GCC permits) and then try to access an element outside the bounds of the array (there are no valid elements in a zero-length array).  Your loop throws away the array and then tries to write outside the bounds of an array that is now of size one (only `new_sd[0]` is valid, but you access `new_sd[1]`). In theory, the old array is abandoned on each iteration and all the values become indeterminate. You need to pre-allocate an array big enough to hold the accepted connections, or use dynamic memory allocation (`malloc()` et al) to create one as you loop.  You should not normally simply add one element to the array on each iteration.  Clearly, there is code missing that actually reads from the accepted socket descriptors.  You'd also need to clean up the array to remove entries where the communication with the client is complete and you have closed the socket descriptor.